# The stackoverflow.com/questions/ask page will not submit

Tags: bug, asking-questions, ask-question-form

I'm trying to post a question.  I've entered a title and body, added 1 tag, and then hit the "Review your Question" button at the bottom of the page.

The page "locks up".  It won't accept any user input; scrolling, clicking, etc.  I can switch tabs in the browser or to other applications, but the Stack Overflow tab remains locked for ~30 seconds.  Then Chrome times it out and gives me the "oh snap, somethings wrong" broken page.

I've repeated the post attempt after logging out and back in, and after a hard refresh and clearing the browser cache.

I've watched in Chrome's dev tools to see if I could find anything of interest, and all I see is a single ajax request to validate the question, which returns in ~50ms with a 200 response.

I'm using Chrome on Linux Mint.

I logged in using Firefox and it worked.  As soon as I clicked the review button, the page scrolled back to the top with a message that it was ready to post.  I scrolled back down, clicked post, and all is well.  The question, in the off chance it matters:  [MySQL UUID function produces the same value when used as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600623/mysql-uuid-function-produces-the-same-value-when-used-as-a-function-parameter)

1. I submitted this meta-question in Chrome, and this update as well.  Also, I am able to edit the other question in Chrome, even though I had to use FF to post it.
2. I just attempted a test post in Chrome (to stackoverflow.com, not meta) and the error reproduces.  I then repeated the test as follows:

   - Disabled all extensions and repeated the test.  Still failed.
   - Opened DevTools, started a memory monitor, and repeated test.  Very minimal memory allocated immediately on the review button click, then nothing until the page 'breaks'.
   - In DevTools, started a performance profile, and repeated test.  I don't see anything particularly outstanding in the results.

[image: performance during review submit]

Comment: Sounds like there might be some Javascript blocking the browser tab and consuming too much memory. If you're using any extensions / addons / userscripts, try disabling them and see if the problem still occurs on Chrome